# How to change drivers using network path name instead of letter.

Tags: windows, hard-drive, command-line, cmd.exe

I'm attempting to write a .bat file

When you open cmd.exe it's defaults to C drive.

There is a mapped network drive \server.name
Multiple users have access to this drive thus the drive letter is labeled differently per user.

So I want this .bat file to take DIR of the folders within \server.name or F:\ drive

My drive is mapped to F: while others might have S:
So if I share the .bat file it won't work for all users.

I want to use a command that will switch the drive using the UNC path name instead of the drive letters.

Thank you.

Comment: Most `cmd` commands accepts UNC paths. However, you could try [`pushd` - `popd` pair](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)

Comment: You have given absolutely no information about what this command file will do: some applications handle UNC names, some don't. You can parse the output of `net use` to find which drive is mapped and, if not, which letters are available. Then change directory to that drive, mapping it first if necessary.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned, the command prompt (CMD) doesn't read UNC/DFS paths, but you can use Powershell.  For example, in a file called test.bat you can put this command

> dir \\mycompany.local\Datafile

and then run

> .\test.bat

To get DIR output.

If you want to run powershell from within the command prompt, you can use this in your batch file:

> powershell.exe "dir \\mycompany.local\Datafile"